# Reference request : How to use Lagrange multiplier technique with infinite (infact uncountably) number of constraints?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a constrained maximization problem (maximizing a functional), with number of constraints being uncountable infinite.

It looks something like this. I want to maximize the convex functional $C(f)$ over $f \in S$ with the constraint that look like $G(f,\phi) = 0 \forall \phi \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Clearly these constraints are infinite in number (infact uncountably  infinite).

I don't know how to use Lagrange multiplier technique in this context. Hence I request for a reference for a theory in this regard. I am not aware of any such concepts and no idea on what terminolgy I should search on google.

Edit : The example cited may not represent a typical case, neverthless I want a reference to the concerned generic theory.

Comment: PDE-constrained optimization is a very big and well-developed field. See here for a quick overview: https://archive.siam.org/meetings/op08/Heinkenschloss.pdf

Comment: The book *Optimization by Vector Space Methods* by David Luenberger is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for optimization in vector spaces (preferably normed spaces). There is a rich theory available. The choice of spaces and norms is not always clear and often the key to the solution. In general, if you have a constraint $g(x)=0$ and $g$ maps into a normed space $X$, then the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ for this constraint is an element in the dual space $X^*$. You would add $\langle \lambda,g(x)\rangle$ to the objective to form the Lagrangian. A classic reference for the practitioner is "Optimization by Vector Space Methods" by Luenberger.

Comment: To be more specific, the functional is $C(f,\alpha)$ where $f$ is a function and $\alpha$ a positive real scalar. It needs to be maximized with respect to both $f$ and $\alpha$. The constraint are  of the form $G(f,\alpha,\phi) = 0, \forall \phi \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$. I hope reference is still applicable as $f$ lies in a vector space. Please confirm. Also the case of Lagrange multipliers in infinite dimensions does not apply here?

Comment: Yes, $f$ in a vector space works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dirk

Comment: In my question the constraints are  $G(f,\phi) = 0 \forall \phi$, while in your answer, you are suggesting to add $\langle \lambda,g(x) \rangle$ to form the Lagrangian. Do you mean $\phi$ itself plays the role of $\lambda$, that is the Lagrange multiplier? (..I want to get clarified before I buy this book).

Comment: The constraint $G(f,\phi)=0$ for all $\phi\in C^\infty$ is a problem in this form. I suspect that the constraint can be modeled in a different way, e.g. as a constraint on $f$ (without using $\phi$), but this is just a guess since I do not know any details.